# client credentials grantype for ride request uber java api?

Tags: java, uber-api

can we use client credentials grantype for ride request using uber java api? if not then is there anyway that we can ride request without end user screen to grant permissins because the case is we want to show and ride request on behalf of one client account to all end users connected to my app?

Answer (score 0):

Uber ride request API does not support client credentials grant.

The end user must explicitly give your app permission to the requested scopes and data.